# Create array of columns letters where column header fulfills criteria

Tags: google-sheets

in Google Sheets using formulars I would like to build an array of the columns that fulfills a simple criteria, so for example:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| h1 | h2 | h2 | h1 | h3 | h2 | h1 |

Then I would like to have the array {A:A,D:D,G:G} if I search for 'h1'

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your raw data is in a sheet named Sheet1.

In a new sheet (e.g., Sheet2), place the following formula in A1:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!A:G,Sheet1!A1:G1="h1"))`

You could also place this version of the formula in Sheet2 cell B1:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!A:G,Sheet2!A1:G1=A1))`

... and then enter "h1" (or some other text to match) into cell A1.

**ADDENDUM** (after further comment from OP):

`=IFERROR(FILTER(REGEXREPLACE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(Sheet2!A:G),4)&":"&ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(Sheet2!A:G),4),"\d",""),Sheet2!A1:G1="h1"))`

Comment: Hi thanks - I hear what you are saying, but I need the output to be an array of the colums that fulfill the criteria and thus I cannot use filter, as that would return the content of the columns

Comment: See the added **Addendum** formula in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is to get the Column letter of the cell if some criteria is met. Like :"what colums have the right answer?" and the return that letter in some way.

So as far as i know sheets does not provide that as a simple function. (But im not very skilled in sheets).

Heres a hacky thing that might work for you:
Somwhere in your sheet (eg bottom row # 100 make cells that hold your letters
So A100 holds "A" or "A:A" B100 holds "B" or "B:B" and so forth.

then you can use filter function.
If the row you want to want to investigate is the first:
code:
=FILTER(A100:Z100;A1:Z1="h2")
that will give you your array.

Cheers Mads

Answer (score 0):

heres a pice of code that will give you the column letter for any column.
Maybe you can use this in your code, or you can paste it in a cell and copy drag vertically it to get the column letters, like i sugested in previous post.

=IF(TRUNC((column()-1)/26)<1;CHAR((MOD((column()-1);26))+65);CHAR(TRUNC((column()-1)/26)+65)&CHAR((MOD((column()-1);26))+65))

Good Luck :)